# How to use jQuery deferred promise to execute many tasks sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, jquery-deferred

I am using a vendor API to access its services. The service is exposed as jQuery deferred object. For one complete business task, I do something like this in pseudo code.

```
service.do('reset').then( function ( result) {
    return service.setValue(valObj);
}).then ( function (result) {
    return service.do('runTask');
}).then ( function ( result ) {
    return service.getResult(query);
}).then ( function (result){
    console.log('finally done with One task');
});
```

Each service.XXX is a REST API call underneath, the call back function bring back the REST response. I omit how each result is used for simplicity.

Now I need to execute this service 100 times in strict end-to-start sequence in a single business task. The above code need to be executed 100 times: previous one is completed then start the next one.

What is a good way to structure such requirement in javascript? I am using ReactJS, and jQuery.

Comment: Did those `result`s really get used?

Comment: did you consider some javascript promise based library like https://github.com/kriskowal/q or https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: I suggest reading this article on Promises. http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html. It's amazing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to execute the same thing over and over, you can just put it in a function and call that function when the last step in the chain finishes:

```
var cntr = 0;
function run() {
    if (cntr++ > 1000) return;
    service.do('reset').then( function ( result) {
        service.setValue(valObj).then ( function (result) {
            service.do('runTask').then ( function ( result ) {
                service.getResult(query).then ( function (result){
                    console.log('finally done with One task');
                    run();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

run();
```

---

FYI, you don't have to so deeply nest things.  You can chain your promises like this:

```
var cntr = 0;
function run() {
    if (cntr++ > 1000) return;
    service.do('reset').then( function ( result) {
        return service.setValue(valObj);
    }).then ( function (result) {
        return service.do('runTask');
    }).then ( function ( result ) {
        return service.getResult(query);
    }).then ( function (result){
        console.log('finally done with One task');
        run();
    });
}

run();
```

Comment: Thanks, it should work. I updated the code to remove the depth.

Comment: @jay.m - FYI, here on StackOverflow, you should not be editing your question to incorporate portions of an answer.  You can edit to clarify your question, but your question should remain your question.  Answers are where solutions or improvements in the code are shown.  Did my answer provide you the info you need?

Comment: thx for reminding, next time I won't. Yes, I voted up your answer.   Do you think the question is clear now? And I am not doing the samething 100 times, each time the inputs and result are different.

Comment: @jay.m - Does my question answer what you were asking?  If so, you can click the green checkmark to indicate to the community that your question was answered.  If not, then please clarify what else you need help with.

Comment: @ jfriend00 did that. Also please vote up my question if you think it is clear and worth your time answering it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using same recursive function

```js
(function tasks(n, complete) {
    return n < complete ? Promise.resolve("a").then(function(result) {
        return Promise.resolve(result + "b").then(function(result) {
            return Promise.resolve(result + "c").then(function(result) {
                return Promise.resolve(result + "d").then(function(result) {
                    console.log("finally done with " + n + " task", result + "" + n);
                }).then(tasks.bind(null, n+1, complete));
            });
        });
    }) : console.log("complete", n, complete)
}(0, 100))
```

Comment: Why all the `Promise.resolve()` statements?  It doesn't seem like those are needed.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
var i = 100;
window.running = false;

while (i > 0 && !window.running) {
    window.running = true;
    i--;

    service.do('reset').then( function ( result) {
        service.setValue(valObj).then ( function (result) {
            service.do('runTask').then ( function ( result ) {
                service.getResult(query).then ( function (result){
                    //...

                    window.running = false;
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: windows.running is not as semaphore, how the loop will sleep on running? Your code will exit out the whiie loop and the task only run once.